# copy a modal but change the text and images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a lot of modal on my site and I don't want to copy paste my code everytime just to change text and images.( all the rest of the modal stays the same).Would be appreciated if someone help me achieve that!

so I have this modaleTemplate i'd like to copy everytime, and then I want to change the following:

-modalImage1
-modalImage2
-modalImage3

-modalTitle
-modalText

```
    <!----------------->
    <!--- PROJECTS 1 -->
    <!----------------->
    <section class="section-full">
        <div class="container-full">

            <div class="portfolio logo" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalProject-1" id="project-1">
                <div class="portfolio-wrapper">             
                    <img src="img/portfolio/logo/5.jpg"/>
                </div>
            </div>              

        </div>
    </section>


    <!------------------->
    <!-------- MODAL 1 -->
    <!------------------->

    <!-- Modal Project Template -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalProject-1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
               <!--modal body-->
               <div class="modal-body">
                   <div class="container-fluid">
                       <div class="row">

                           <!--modal image-->
                           <div class="col-sm-6">
                               <img id="modalImage1"/>
                               <img id="modalImage2"/>
                               <img id="modalImage3"/>
                           </div>
                           <!--modal text-->
                           <div class="col-sm-6">
                               <h2 id="modalTitle"></h2>
                               <p id="modalText"></p>
                           </div>

                      </div>
                  </div>
               </div><!--modal body-->
           </div><!--modal-content-->
        </div><!--modal-dialog-->
    </div>

    <!--------------------->
    <!-- modal project 1 --> 
    <!---------------------> 
    <script>
    $('#project-1').click(function(){
        function setModal(modalImage1, modalImage2, modalImage3, modalTitle, modalText){
            $('#modalImage1').attr('src','img/portfolio/logo/1.jpg');
            $('#modalImage2').attr('src','img/portfolio/logo/2.jpg');
            $('#modalImage3').attr('src','img/portfolio/logo/3.jpg');
            $('#modalTitle').text('some title');
            $('#modalText').text( 'some text' );
        };
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Which library are you using? Could you provide a working snippet?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap 4,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery (or vanilla javascript) to change the values of DOM when opening the modal.
Remove the `<script>` tags that you have placed in the modal give id (or class) to elements that you set the value to on the open-event.
To change src of an image in jQuery you can use `$('#ID-of-img').attr('src','path-here');`.
To change the text of a header or paragraph (or whatever) in jQuery you can use `$('#ID-of-element').text('place text here');`.

In your case I would use something like this.

```
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="spacer-sm hidden-sm-up"></div>
            <h2 id="modalTitleDef"></h2>
            <p><span id="modalText1Def"></span><br><br><span id="modalText2Def"></span></p>
            <br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" data-dismiss="modal">Close Project</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>    

<!-- project1 = COPY ALL modalTemplate but CHANGE the images and text-->   
<script>   

    function setModal(modalImage1Def, modalImage2Def, modalImage3Def, modalTitle, modalText1, modalText2){
        $('#modalImage1Def').attr('src',modalImage1Def);
        $('#modalImage2Def').attr('src',modalImage2Def);
        $('#modalImage3Def').attr('src',modalImage3Def);
        $('#modalTitleDef').text(modalTitle);
        $('#modalText1Def').text(modalText1);
        $('#modalText2Def').text(modalText2);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll try that!:)

Comment: Good answer, Anders. Keep 'em coming! +1 *(It's also a good idea to add a Demo to your answer to help the questioner immediately see your ideas in action - just press Control+M in the answer dialog)*

Comment: Tnx. Just added some code to show a way on how to solve this case.

Comment: Hi I tried everything but it doesn't seem to be working. I've uptdated my code you mind checking it out? thanks :)!

Comment: nevermind I got it! I just removed this line and it worked! :

function setModal(modalImage1Def, modalImage2Def, modalImage3Def, modalTitle, modalText1, modalText2){

Answer (score 1):

It's a lot simpler than you may realize.

Especially when using the excellent Bootstrap modals, the modal is just a DIV structure that is initially hidden, and then displayed. It is styled using `position:absolute` or `position:fixed` to put it overtop of the page, and that adds to its mystique. But it is nothing more than a simple DIV structure.

So, how do you programmatically change the contents of a normal div? Usually, we use jQuery `.html()` -- and that's how you can have one modal structure and change the contents as desired.

Usually, you only need to have one modal structure on the page, and then every time you wish to display info in a modal you change the contents of that structure and re-display the updated modal.

Example:

```js
$('#changeit').click(function(){
   $('.modal-header').html('New header title');
   $('.modal-body').html('\
      <div class="col-xs-4">\
        <img src="http://placeimg.com/200/150/animals" >\
      </div>\
      <div class="col-xs-8">\
        Here is some new content. Here is some new content. Here is some new content. Here is some new content. Here is some new content. Here is some new content. Here is some new content. \
      </div>');
    alert('Modal has been changed. Click OPEN MODAL again to see');
  //$('#btnOpenModal').click(); //This will force re-open the modal, if desired
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button id="btnOpenModal" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>


<!-- Simple Modal, from http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<button id="changeit">Change Modal Contents</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your situation is the exact example for using template, you have some HTML need to be rendered in different places and variables to change, Please check [JavaScript templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript_templates)